# JSON substitution with PHP

Tags: php, json, elasticsearch

I'm trying to populate some json (an elasticsearch query) with a variable passed by a form, but it's not working because I can't seem to preserve the double quotes.  Here's what I'm trying to reproduce - let's say 'smith' is being passed by the form:

```
 $plast_name = "{$_GET["lname"]}";

 $json = '{
         "query" : {
             "match" : {
                 "last_name" : "smith"
                 }
         } }';
```

... and here's my latest of many attempts:

```
 $plast_name = "{$_GET["lname"]}";

 $json = '{
        "query" : {
             "match" : {
                 "last_name" : ' . "$plast_name" . '
                 }
         } }';
```

Comment: Your first line is killing the script: `$plast_name = $_GET["lname"];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign $_GET value to an array and then use json_encode().

```
<?php
$value['last_name'] =$_GET['lname'];
echo json_encode($value);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `json_encode()` on an array, and `json_decode()` on a json string. No need to manually create json.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys!